# how to get index of Dataframes after sorting

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

when I apply sort function to Dataframe index are not printed only values are printed

I have tried .index along with sort but not working

```
Andhra Pradesh                609949.85
Arunachal Pradesh              18796.07
Assam                         224247.19
Bihar                         413513.59
Chhattisgarh                  260786.98
Goa                            45012.75
```

I want sorted numbers and print index on left side

```
Andhra Pradesh                609949.85
Bihar                         413513.59
Chhattisgarh                  260786.98
Assam                         224247.19
Goa                            45012.75
Arunachal Pradesh              18796.07
```

Comment: What function are you using exactly, what language are you using, how does your data look and what are you trying to do exactly? Can you be more specific with your question?

Comment: @Sai Ramarao, see the answer, also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `pandas` we have `sort_values`

```
df=df.sort_values('col')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

**The `ascending=False` is to order the dataframe in descending order, by default it is `True`.**

```
df.sort_values(by=['col'], ascending=False)
```

### DataFrame:

```
>>> df
               Col_1      Col_2
0     Andhra Pradesh  609949.85
1  Arunachal Pradesh   18796.07
2              Assam  224247.19
3              Bihar  413513.59
4       Chhattisgarh  260786.98
5                Goa   45012.75
```

### Result:

```
>>> df.sort_values(by=['Col_2'], ascending=False)
               Col_1      Col_2
0     Andhra Pradesh  609949.85
3              Bihar  413513.59
4       Chhattisgarh  260786.98
2              Assam  224247.19
5                Goa   45012.75
1  Arunachal Pradesh   18796.07
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
indexx = ["Andhra Pradesh","Arunachal Pradesh","Assam","Bihar","Chhattisgarh","Goa"]
values = [609949.85,18796.07,224247.19,413513.59,260786.98,45012.75] 
df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=indexx, columns=['value'])

print(df["value"].sort_values(ascending=False))

Andhra Pradesh       609949.85
Bihar                413513.59
Chhattisgarh         260786.98
Assam                224247.19
Goa                   45012.75
Arunachal Pradesh     18796.07
```